# Multivariate LSTM RNN DNN returning multiple features for forecasting a time series in Python

Tags: keras, time-series, rnn, python-3.x, features

I am using the latest installation of **Keras** with Python 3.6 on Linux Mint with a NVIDIA (NVDA) 2070 GPU.
I am looking up. How to get the return values of my data? How do I use all of the features, and then get a return for each one, 1 time step into the future. **Also**, is there a way to only get certain features. Let's say.

Date Open High Low Close 50sma Volume

How would I return only the Open High Low and Close for the next day?

I have read many past questions and tutorials, but they are not fully intact. They are usually missing parts of the code or authors or columnists (pun not intended) won't answer. (Yes, I understand. There is the most serious pandemic going on.) So, thanks ahead of time for your time. Also, if there is specific reference. I would love to see it. 
I have looked over Keras and Tensorflow Documentation, too. Maybe, I just don't get it, and could someone please point out specifically. What I am missing?